# Gulp copy subdirectories

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want to copy a folder with sub folders and files with Gulp.

```
gulp.src('resources/assets/admin/js/vendor/**/*.{js,css,png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/vendor/'))
    .pipe(notify({message: 'Vendor: moved', onLast: true}));
```

This structure is copied:

- vendor/foo/script.js
- vendor/foo/bar/script.js

But not:

- vendor/foo/bar/foobar/script.js

Can someone explain why it is ignoring some sub folders. Please HELP ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and I found that adding `base` as a parameter preserved the folder structure of your source.

```
gulp.src('resources/assets/admin/js/vendor/**/*.{js,css,png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}',{
        base: 'vendor'
    })
.pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/vendor/'))
.pipe(notify({message: 'Vendor: moved', onLast: true}));
```

Check out the gulp docs here for src options
https://gulp.readme.io/docs/gulpsrcglobs-options#section-options-base